# Can't see Materialized Views from a Linked Server in SQL Server with PostgreSQL 11

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2012 and PostgreSQL11, SQL Server sees all tables and views in PostgreSQL11, except materialized views.

Comment: What exactly does "can't see" mean? SSMS is not designed to support management of any other type of database engine. If you need to manage a Postgres server/database, you should use an appropriate tool for that.

Comment: through Management Studio 2012 in the Object Browser section, I don't see the materialized view, and I can't select from it